# Multidimensional array sorting

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have the following array:

```
array
(
[0]=>array
        (
            [0]=>array
            (
                  [value]=>3.5
                  [id] =>1
                  )
                 [1]=>array
                 (
                  [value]=>1.5
                  [id] =>2
                  )
                 [2]=>array
                 (
                  [value]=>1.5
                  [id] =>3
                  )
            )
        )
[1]=>array
        (
            [0]=>array
            (
                  [value]=>4.5
                  [id] =>1
                  )
                 [1]=>array
                 (
                  [value]=>5.5
                  [id] =>2
                  )
                 [2]=>array
                 (
                  [value]=>6.5
                  [id] =>3
                  )
            )
        )
)
```

I want to sort the array by value where the id is equal, what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Altering the top-level structure, moving elements between top level arrays?  How does your sort need to function in the higher dimension?

Comment: Yes, I want to sort the top level, by values where the id equal.

Comment: Top-level has multiple values, how to handle that?

Comment: For example sort by values where the ids equal 1

Comment: I still do not have a clear idea of how you are defining this sort.  Are you saying to treat it as a flat list, or retain the structure.  If you are retaining the structure what dictates if one top level is before or after another.  You keep saying "where the id equal", sorting is about ordering, `< = >`, not just equality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying my luck…

```
<?php

$data = array(
    array( /* #1 */
        array('value' => 3.5, 'id' => 1),
        array('value' => 1.5, 'id' => 2),
        array('value' => 1.5, 'id' => 3)
    ),
    array( /* #2 */
        array('value' => 4.5, 'id' => 1),
        array('value' => 5.5, 'id' => 2),
        array('value' => 6.5, 'id' => 3)
    )
);

/* Merge #1 and #2 into one array */
$tmp = array();
foreach ($data as $firstDimension) {
    $tmp = array_merge($tmp, $firstDimension);
}

/* Sort by id (1st, ASC) and value (2nd, DESC) */
usort($tmp, function ($a, $b) {
    $d = $a['id'] - $b['id'];

    if ($d !== 0) {
        return $d;
    }

    return $b['value'] - $a['value'];
});

/* Group entries by id */
$grouped = array();
$c = 0;
foreach ($tmp as $entry) {
    if ($c > 0 && $grouped[$c - 1]['id'] === $entry['id']) {
        $grouped[$c - 1]['values'][] = $entry['value'];
    } else {
        $grouped[] = array('id'     => $entry['id'],
                           'values' => array($entry['value']));
        $c++;
    }
}
unset($tmp);

print_r($grouped);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [values] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 4.5
                    [1] => 3.5
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [values] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 5.5
                    [1] => 1.5
                )

        )
[...]
```